# HTML code: where can I find the font and color for the title on a page

Tags: html, fonts, colors

I am new to HTML coding. I am trying to find out how to change the colour and font of the title on an HTML page. The title is in highlighted black, as the text: [About CPOM](https://cpom.org.uk/about/).

Can anyone help with this?

I assume it is given at the beginning of the page code, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />  

  <link rel="pingback" href="https://cpom.org.uk/xmlrpc.php"> 
<title>About CPOM - CPOM</title>

<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v5.8 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<link rel="canonical" href="https://cpom.org.uk/about/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="About CPOM - CPOM" />
<meta property="og:description" content="CPOM studies land ice, sea ice and ice sheets using satellite observations and numerical models of the polar regions.  Importantly, we provide UK National Capability in Earth observation and modelling of the cryosphere &#8211; the frozen parts of our planet.  Our...Read more" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://cpom.org.uk/about/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="CPOM" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://cpom.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Antarctic-ice-loss-CPOM-ESA.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://cpom.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Antarctic-ice-loss-CPOM-ESA.jpg" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="CPOM studies land ice, sea ice and ice sheets using satellite observations and numerical models of the polar regions.  Importantly, we provide UK National Capability in Earth observation and modelling of the cryosphere &#8211; the frozen parts of our planet.  Our...Read more" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="About CPOM - CPOM" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://cpom.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Antarctic-ice-loss-CPOM-ESA.jpg" />
<script type='application/ld+json'>{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"WebSite","@id":"#website","url":"https:\/\/cpom.org.uk\/","name":"CPOM","potentialAction":{"@type":"SearchAction","target":"https:\/\/cpom.org.uk\/?s={search_term_string}","query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}}</script>
<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, that I understand you correctly, but look at the picture below maybe it helps you.[image]

Comment: @ Gh111 - that was helpful! I now found out how inspect the elements to help me understand the layout and details of the page.